# pass formControl value to function, null

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have simple input and button:

```html
<label for="code">Join session: </label>
<input
  id="code"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Session code"
  [formControl]="code"
  maxlength="6"
><button
  [disabled]="code.invalid"
  (click)="joinSession(code.value)"
>Enter</button>
```

And my component:

```js
export class JoinSessionComponent {
  public code = new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$"),
    Validators.minLength(6),
  ])

  public joinSession(code: string) {
    console.log(code)
  }
}
```

Error is:

> Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

Caused by the `joinSession(code.value)` in the template. The error sort of makes sense since the code formControl *could* be resetted to a `null` value, but my validators make sure that it has a correct value before a user can pass the code.

Is there a way to make this work in the template or do I have to use the code formControl in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple typing issue.

Your form value can be a string or it can be null.

Your function is expecting a string.

You can change your function to
`public joinSession(code: string | null)`

And code.invalid is only populated once the form control is dirty. So if you don't touch the form control, invalid isn't triggered.

Better to test `[disabled]="!code.valid"`